# Missing a detail about Chinese Remainder Theorem and $Z$ Ring isomorphisms.

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem, ring-isomorphism

I'm trying to prove that $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}$ holds only when $\gcd(m,n)=1$ or in simpler terms when $n,m$ are coprime integers. So far I understand how a simple construction can be used when the condition is met to show that there exists a bijection such as:  $$\psi\colon \mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \ \psi(x)=(x \bmod n, x \bmod m)$$
However what I'm missing here is where exactly do we need the requirement that $\gcd(m,n)=1$?

Comment: Try an extreme case such as $m=n$. Do you see why $\psi$ fails to be a bijection?

Comment: And of course, one needs to show that there is no isomorphism. This usually involves exhibiting a property (invariant under isomorphism) that one side has and the other fails to have.

Comment: I’m pretty sure $\phi$, as you defined it, goes the other way. You don’t need $gcd = 1$ to show that $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism, but you do need it to show $\phi$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly observe that the kernel of the map defined from $\mathbb{Z}$ is $m\mathbb{Z}\cap n\mathbb{Z}$ which is equal to $mn\mathbb{Z}$ only when $m,n$ are coprime.

Secondly try to show that the map is surjective. Here also you will require the comaximality condition.